# Android App - Possible to modify a string in Constants.java?

Tags: java, android, constants

So, I'm not a master of Java but I wanted to help a friend of mine with an app.
The situation is that, I have a Social Network app, with more than 100 public static final strings in Constants.java like this:

```
public static final String METHOD_FRIENDS_REQUEST = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/friends.sendRequest" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;
public static final String METHOD_FRIENDS_ACCEPT = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/friends.acceptRequest" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;
public static final String METHOD_FRIENDS_REJECT = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/friends.rejectRequest" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;
public static final String METHOD_FRIENDS_REMOVE = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/friends.remove" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;
public static final String METHOD_FRIENDS_GET = API_DOMAIN + "api/" + API_VERSION + "/method/friends.get" + API_FILE_EXTENSION;
```

the API_VERSION is declared like this:

```
public static final String API_VERSION = "v2";
```

And I have to be able to modify the value of API_VERSION while using the app.
(eg: A toggle button in LoginActivity.java to modify the value of API_VERSION from "v2" to "v3".

I know how to put the button with a click listener, to use set and get method etc. But if you have any idea of what could be the best way to do that ? I saw that in Constants.java, I can't use functions?

Thank's in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is "simple" : you have to design the design point of your application. Constants are not meant to be changed at runtime.

This means: you need a way to compute the values those friends strings dynamically! Like: have a class with getter methods that each return such a string. You give the version string to the constructor of that class - so that

```
 public String getRequest() {
```

Can return a result depending on the version string passed earlier on.